# Hover effect for every square takes more squares than it should

Tags: css, grid, hover

In this simple grid created with html and css I need a hover effect for every square but it´s taking more squares then it should. The wrapper may be the problem but I´m not sure why.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

div div:hover {
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <body>

    <h1>Basic Grid with Hover Effect</h1>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row1">
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <div id="id2"></div>
        <div id="id3"></div>
        <div id="id4"></div>
        <div id="id5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div id="id16"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row3">
        <div id="id15"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row4">
        <div id="id14"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row5">
        <div id="id13"></div>
        <div id="id12"></div>
        <div id="id11"></div>
        <div id="id10"></div>
        <div id="id9"></div>
    </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an html where there are 3 levels of **div**

So your selector **div div** selects both the rows and the cells

I have changed your row classes to one, to be abled to use it and make the selector more specific

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.row div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.row div:hover {
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <body>

    <h1>Basic Grid with Hover Effect</h1>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <div id="id2"></div>
        <div id="id3"></div>
        <div id="id4"></div>
        <div id="id5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id16"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id15"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id14"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id13"></div>
        <div id="id12"></div>
        <div id="id11"></div>
        <div id="id10"></div>
        <div id="id9"></div>
    </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close the `head` tag.

I would recommend deleting all the `row` classes in the wrapper because you are using `float`, your divs are aligned anyway.

Classes are supposed to be uniform and not unique, in this code here you use the `row`-classes like `id`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

div div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

div div:hover {
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Basic Grid with Hover Effect</h1>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <div id="id2"></div>
        <div id="id3"></div>
        <div id="id4"></div>
        <div id="id5"></div>
        <div id="id16"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id6"></div>
        <div id="id15"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id7"></div>
        <div id="id14"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="0"></div>
        <div id="id8"></div>
        <div id="id13"></div>
        <div id="id12"></div>
        <div id="id11"></div>
        <div id="id10"></div>
        <div id="id9"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```